# how to use firestoreConnect to get multiple databases to a redux firestore database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am trying this code in my react app and wanted to get **notifications** **collection** from the firestore database

```
export default compose(
    firestoreConnect(() => [
        {collection: "projects"},
        {collection: "notifications", limit: 3}
    ]),
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(dashboard)
```

But I am getting this error

> redux-firestore listener error: FirebaseError: "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Although, I am able to get projects collection but when I write code for notifications collections I am getting the above bold error text in console.

Comment: It sounds like you don't grant the user permission to read the `notifications` collection in your database's security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

Comment: Yes , you are right. I have to add a new rule for this data. Thank You